# Unable to run 'lein repl' with error NoSuchMethodError 'java.io.OutputStream org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole.wrapOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream)'

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I am trying to start off my local lein server with repl, but the following errors pop up.

```
REPL-y 0.5.1, nREPL 0.8.3
Clojure 1.10.3
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.2+8
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

NoSuchMethodError 'java.io.OutputStream org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole.wrapOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream)'
        jline.AnsiWindowsTerminal.detectAnsiSupport (AnsiWindowsTerminal.java:57)
        jline.AnsiWindowsTerminal.<init> (AnsiWindowsTerminal.java:27)
        jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (:-2)
        jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (:-1)
        jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (:-1)
        java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller (:-1)
        java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance (:-1)
        jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance (:-1)
        java.lang.Class.newInstance (:-1)
        jline.TerminalFactory.getFlavor (TerminalFactory.java:205)
        jline.TerminalFactory.create (TerminalFactory.java:96)
        jline.TerminalFactory.get (TerminalFactory.java:180)
Bye for now!
```

Anyone have idea on the cause and solution.

Comment: Looks like a versioning thing. You need to ensure you have the right version of jansi for your version of jline. Looks like the latest jline is jline3, which uses jansi 2.4.0

Comment: Can you show your `project.clj` contents? And also the exact `lein` command you typed? That will help identify the issue.

Comment: For me this error was caused by lein plugin [lein-ancient "1.0.0-RC4-SNAPSHOT"]